# Strange position of unicode square root glyph (U+221A) in Latin Modern Math

Tags: unicode-math, latin-modern

Why is the square root glyph (U+221A) positioned so strangely in Latin Modern Math?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\(2 \sqrt{2} √2\)
\qquad
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\(2 \sqrt{2} √2\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the font metrics have been derived from the legacy font? This seems the only likely answer. In the original TeX symbol font, where the radical symbol lives, the height of the character is used to set the thickness of the vinculum. The position of the symbol is then adjusted following other rules.

Comment: I get the same error if I remove both `\setmathfont`s. So it's not necessarily related to the font choice and to Latin Modern Math (as much as `unicode-math` maybe, or the sqrt character you input?). [This is on TeXLive 2020.]

Comment: @marquinho Latin Modern Math is the default font; I added setmathfont for that font in my code for clarity. The input is the actual unicode character (U+221A: √) as UTF-8. Using LuaLaTeX on updated TeXLive 2021.

Comment: @Jostein Thanks for the explanation, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In legacy math fonts, the character for the radical is taken from font family 2 for “standard” size and from font family 3 for larger sizes.

The character sits in either case in slot `"70` (decimal 112), but the large symbols font (family 3) has instructions to choose larger sizes.

In order to save memory space, Knuth decided that this character should incorporate some parameter in its metrics: in particular, the character's height tells TeX how thick the vinculum should be. The actual positioning of the symbol and of the vinculum depends on different rules.

Indeed, if you run this simple command line

```
pdftex '\showthe\fontcharht\textfont3 "70'
```

you will get

```
> 0.39998pt.
```

(which is how TeX stores 0.4pt, because of rounding to scaled points).

If you look in plain TeX, you will see the line

```
\def\surd{{\mathchar"1270}}
```

so that `\surd` places the radical sign symmetrically around the formula axis because `\mathchar"1270` declares a math operator and, by TeX rule, such a character will be placed like that; the braces hide the operator nature.

The same of course happens for `lmex10`, because otherwise the radicals would not print correctly.

I guess that, when the people at GUST converted the legacy Latin Modern fonts to OpenType, the height of the radical symbol has remained “very small”. It actually is zero and I have no idea why, but a hint might be that, when OpenType math fonts are used, the thickness of the vinculum is stated in the MATH table, so the character's height is irrelevant.

The developers of STIX fonts decided to have the character at its proper height and XITS Math is essentially the original STIX font with a MATH table added.

If you want that the character behaves like `\surd` in plain TeX or LaTeX, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newunicodechar{√}{{\mathop{\Umathchar "1 "0 `√}}}

\begin{document}

\(2 \sqrt{2} √2\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the legacy

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\(2 \sqrt{2} \surd 2\)

\end{document}
```

and see that the output is the same.

Comment: Regarding the height of the OpenType symbol "being zero": Height of OpenType symbols is not really well defined since the height isn't stored in the file, so it's mostly guessed based on the bounding box. For LuaTeX, you therefore get a height of 0.4pt since that's the height of the bounding box. XeTeX on the other hand rounds all heights smaller or equal than 4% of the fontsize to zero, therefore 0.4pt gets rounded to 0.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Nice to know, thanks!

Comment: When I load Latin Modern Math v1.959 into FontForge, I can see that the Em size is 1000, the highest y-coordinate of 0x221A is +40 while the lowest is -960. I can "fix" the output from the MWE by moving up the glyph and generate a new font file. I checked some other math fonts, and they all have a more "proper" y-position of their surds. Could this be a bug in LM Math?

Comment: @JosteinTrondal At this point in time, it has become a feature. :-)

Comment: @egreg Sensible conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use an active character or the `\surd` macro, you could give the character mathclass 1 so it is automatically a `\mathop` and vertically centred.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}



\begin{document}
\Umathcode `√ 1 3 `√

\(2 \sqrt{2} √2\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Math class 1, you mean. But the spacing would be wrong

Comment: @egreg oops fixed, different not necessarily wrong, arguably the character is being used as a mathop if you use it as `√2`